# JQuery Ajax Updating MySQL Database, But Not Running Success Function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am currently using the JQuery ajax function to call an exterior PHP file, in which I select and add data in a database. Once this is done, I run a success function in JavaScript. What's weird is that the database is updating successfully when ajax is called, however the success function is not running. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div onclick="addtask();" style="width:400px; height:200px; background:#000000;"></div>
<script>
function addtask() {
var tid = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)) + 1;
var tsk = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)) + 1;

if(tsk !== 1) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "taskcheck.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {taskid:tid},
    success: function(task) {alert(task.name);}
    });
}
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the PHP file:

```
session_start(); 

$connect = mysql_connect('x', 'x', 'x') or die('Not Connecting'); 
mysql_select_db('x') or die ('No Database Selected'); 

$task = $_REQUEST['taskid']; 
$uid = $_SESSION['user_id']; 

$q = "SELECT task_id, taskname FROM tasks WHERE task_id=" .$task. " LIMIT 1"; 
$gettask = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($q)); 

$q = "INSERT INTO user_tasks (ut_id, user_id, task_id, taskstatus, taskactive) VALUES (null, " .$uid. ", '{$gettask['task_id']}', 0, 1)"; 
$puttask = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($q)); 

$json = array( 
    "name" => $gettask['taskname'] 
); 

$output = json_encode($json); 
echo $output;
```

Let me know if you have any questions or comments, thanks.

[image]

Comment: Use the Developer Tools' or Firebug's Net panel to see what happened to the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ibelieve it runs but alert wont show because of error -

```
success: function(task) {alert(task.name);}
```

You have to decode JSON first with `jQuery.parseJSON()`, task is just a string
it shoudld look somthing like this

```
function(m)
        {
            var task = jQuery.parseJSON( m );
            alert(task['name']);
        }
```

Edit:
Ok ... 
Try to use developer tools in your browser and place breakpoint on your success function, if it doesnt even lunch try to add error callback for your ajax call

```
error: function(xhr, exc)
{
   alert(xhr.status);
   alert(exc);
}
```

Edit2:
and there is your problem - your ajax is not only returning json data, but php warning too, and now I see where is your problem - you are fetching data after insert, delete

```
$puttask = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($q));
```

Now I feel bad for not noticing it sooner...

Comment: `dataType: "json"` should take care of decoding.

Comment: adding that code doesn't make any difference. i'm using various ajax json calls within other sections of my code, and the success function works just fine. just not this one :/

Comment: ok, for the xhr.status alert i get '200' and the exc 'parsererror'

Comment: hmm ... there might be problem parsing json, try to switch to `datatype: "text"` and use my first solution, or just `alert(m);` to see what is it returning

Comment: the alert still won't show, but with the datatype as text and your code above, the error alerts don't show either. the database is still updated

Comment: try `function(m)
        {
            alert(m);
        }` in success with `datatype: "text"`, also install chrome, start developer tools(Ctrl+Shift+i) and check network tab after running that ajax. Look for the php you are calling, and add its header and response to your question please

Comment: i've attached a screenshot of that code when run in the original question

Comment: thank you! don't feel bad, i never would have noticed it myself. it works now, again thank you for your help